# Is it okay to ignore someone at work?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior

My question involves work related. There's this woman at my job who I truly dislike. We started off as friends but all that changed when she spread bad rumors about me behind my back. I didn't want to confront her about the incident but as of late I've been giving her the cold shoulders lately. Whenever I see her, I walk away really fast and when we walked pass each other I turn my back away from her. I don't think I can ever get over that. She tried to apologize but I rejected. I can never forgive a gossiper. My reputation could've been ruined.

Comment: You say your question is work-related, but you *have not actually asked a question*. Ranty complaint does not count.

Comment: You need to behave professionally to everyone at work whether you like or respect them or not. What you say you are doing is immature and makes you look much worse that she looks out of this whole thing. You may need to actually do some work with this person or her friends at some point and you can't let personal feelings get in the way of what you are paid to do. There will be people you dislike at every job. You still need to work with them. This is not school or the playground where you can afford to have cliques who cut each other out.

Comment: "I can never forgive a gossiper". Never? She has not chances at redemption? That seems a little extreme, especially she has tried to apologize. Human interactions can be super messy but ignoring someone is just going to make it worse. Accept the apology, it doesn't mean you have to be friends. If it happens again, go to HR.

Answer (score 13):

> She tried to apologize but I rejected.

Well that's kind of a wobble on your part. An accepted apology puts the past behind and allows the parties to get along civilly again. If that's what you want, you should accept the apology.

> I can never forgive a gossiper.

Accepting an apology is different from forgiveness. Accepting an apology just means you won't hold a grudge against the apologizing party, not that you have forgiven them for their transgressions.

> Whenever I see her, I walk away really fast and when we walked pass each other I turn my back away from her.

This sounds absolutely infantile. I suggest you cut that out if you want to maintain any semblance of professionalism.

Comment: "My reputation could've been ruined" is pretty telling that the last line is of particular importance, or should be if the line in OP is true.

Comment: You don't have to like or respect someone to be civil. At work, you need to be civil to everyone, no matter what else has happened between you.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it okay to ignore someone at work?

Not in the manner you describe, it makes you look petty and harms your reputation. In addition you will eventually put more people against you, and it is bad for office morale in general. Lastly it makes cooperative team effort more challenging if there is ever a need.